# Postgres: Find position of a specific row within a resultset?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pagination

I'm trying to figure out how to get the relative position of a single item in a query relative to all the items returned from the query.

For example,the long hand way of getting the answer would be:

```
single_item = SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=65
result = SELECT * FROM table WHERE published_date < date_value
x=1
foreach(result as item):
    if(item.id == single_item.id):
        required_value = x
    endif
    x++
endforeach
```

Is there a simple way of getting `required_value` just through a single postgres query?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [analytic/ranking/windowing functionality - 8.4 documentation link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-window.html):

```
WITH summary AS (
   SELECT t.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.published_date) AS position
     FROM TABLE t)
SELECT s.*
  FROM summary s
 WHERE s.id = 65
```

Alternate without the `WITH` syntax:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.published_date) AS position
          FROM TABLE t) s
 WHERE s.id = 65
```

The `position` column will be an integer value representing the location of the record where the `id` value is 65, based on the `published_date` column in ascending order.  If you want the position value to be duplicated when there are ties, replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`